# The type was not mapped after trying to scaffolded controller in browser

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, scaffolding

I am getting the error:

> The type 'GMS_Sandbox_MVC.Models.Organization' was not mapped. Check
>   that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore
>   method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was
>   defined as a class, is not primitive, nested or generic, and does not
>   inherit from EntityObject.
>   Source File: C:\source temp\GMS_Sandbox_MVC\GMS_Sandbox_MVC\Models\OrganizationRepository.cs> > Line: 14

Source Error:

```
Line 12:     {
Line 13:        // GMSSandboxMVCContext context = new GMSSandboxMVCContext();
Line 14:          GMSSandboxMVCContext context = new GMSSandboxMVCContext();
Line 15: 
Line 16:         public IQueryable<Organization> All
```

Anybody have any ideas what might be causing this?

In error log it says:

> Error 12  The type or namespace name 'GMSSandboxMVCEntities' could not
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\source
>   temp\GMS_Sandbox_MVC\GMS_Sandbox_MVC\Models\OrganizationRepository.cs

**OrganizationRepository.CS**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web;

namespace GMS_Sandbox_MVC.Models
{ 
public class OrganizationRepository : IOrganizationRepository
{
   // GMSSandboxMVCContext context = new GMSSandboxMVCContext();
     GMSSandboxMVCContext context = new GMSSandboxMVCContext();

    public IQueryable<Organization> All
    {
        get { return context.Organizations; }
    }

    public IQueryable<Organization> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<Organization, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<Organization> query = context.Organizations;
        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties) {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }
        return query;
    }

    public Organization Find(string id)
    {
        return context.Organizations.Find(id);
    }

    public void InsertOrUpdate(Organization organization)
    {
        if (organization.org_nbr == default(string)) {
            // New entity
            context.Organizations.Add(organization);
        } else {
            // Existing entity
            context.Entry(organization).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }

    public void Delete(string id)
    {
        var organization = context.Organizations.Find(id);
        context.Organizations.Remove(organization);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public interface IOrganizationRepository
{
    IQueryable<Organization> All { get; }
    IQueryable<Organization> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<Organization, object>>[] includeProperties);
    Organization Find(string id);
    void InsertOrUpdate(Organization organization);
    void Delete(string id);
    void Save();
}
```

}
**OrganizationController.CS**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using GMS_Sandbox_MVC.Models;

namespace GMS_Sandbox_MVC.Controllers
{   
    public class OrganizationController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IOrganizationRepository organizationRepository;

        // If you are using Dependency Injection, you can delete the following constructor
        public OrganizationController() : this(new OrganizationRepository())
        {
        }

        public OrganizationController(IOrganizationRepository organizationRepository)
        {
            this.organizationRepository = organizationRepository;
        }

        //
        // GET: /Organizations/

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            return View(organizationRepository.AllIncluding(organization => organization.Assoc_Role, organization => organization.Grants, organization => organization.Distro_List));
        }

        //
        // GET: /Organizations/Details/5

        public ViewResult Details(string id)
        {
            return View(organizationRepository.Find(id));
        }

        //
        // GET: /Organizations/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        } 

        //
        // POST: /Organizations/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Organization organization)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                organizationRepository.InsertOrUpdate(organization);
                organizationRepository.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            } else {
                return View();
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Organizations/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
             return View(organizationRepository.Find(id));
        }

        //
        // POST: /Organizations/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Organization organization)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                organizationRepository.InsertOrUpdate(organization);
                organizationRepository.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            } else {
                return View();
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Organizations/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(string id)
        {
            return View(organizationRepository.Find(id));
        }

        //
        // POST: /Organizations/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string id)
        {
            organizationRepository.Delete(id);
            organizationRepository.Save();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

I am using tutorial from [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/paullitwin/archive/2011/08/11/use-mvc-scaffolding-in-database-first-mode.aspx)

Comment: i think we are going to need to see a few more lines of code.

have you checked that all the conditions listed in the error are ok?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into almost this exact scenario and couldn't find much guidance. I eventually found a couple of things which could be worth trying if anyone else is in a similar position:

1. Delete and recreate your edmx - didn't work for me but worth a go!
2. Make sure you have the latest version of EF installed - I had high hopes in this but still no luck.
3. http://jameschambers.com/blog/asp.net-mvcscaffolding-generates-extra-properties-in-views - I have another error now (possibly due to [complex keys](http://mvcscaffolding.codeplex.com/workitem/31?PendingVoteId=31)) but I'm pretty sure this has solved the previous one!